# Passing updates back to sql server from a datagrid viewer

Tags: c#, sql

I have an sqladapter declared inside a private void and I cant refence it for the update void.
Can anyone advise where I should declare it so it is available in the whole script please?

SqlAdapter is called sqlDataAdap.

The sqladapter is declared in the GetList void and then needs to be called in here but cant be referenced.

```
 private void UpdateRowToDatabase() {
        if (LastDataRow!=null) {
          if (LastDataRow.RowState==
              DataRowState.Modified) {
            sqlDataAdap.Update(LastDataRow);
          }
        }
      }
```

Cheers for the help - it's hard being a newb again!
Dave

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient; //For SQL Connection



namespace Reference_Table_Updater
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }


    void GetList()
        {

        String strConnection = "server=myserver';" +
                   "Database='Scratchpad';" +
                   "Integrated Security=SSPI";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        sqlCmd.Connection = con;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from dbo.UPDATE_Test";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        //con.Close();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {            
        GetList();
    }

       private DataRow LastDataRow = null;


  private void UpdateRowToDatabase() {
    if (LastDataRow!=null) {
      if (LastDataRow.RowState==
          DataRowState.Modified) {
        sqlDataAdap.Update(LastDataRow);
      }
    }
  }

  private void regionBindingSource_PositionChanged(
    object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {

BindingSource thisBindingSource = 
  (BindingSource)sender;
DataRow ThisDataRow=
  ((DataRowView)thisBindingSource.Current).Row;
if (ThisDataRow==LastDataRow) {

  throw new ApplicationException("It seems the" +
    " PositionChanged event was fired twice for" + 
    " the same row");
}

UpdateRowToDatabase();

LastDataRow = ThisDataRow;
  }

  private void MainForm_FormClosed(
    object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) 
  {
    UpdateRowToDatabase();
  }
}
    }
```

Comment: You need : dtRecord.AcceptChanges();

Comment: Ok thanks - where do I need to add it?

Comment: When you want to save data back to database.

Comment: I meant where exactly in the code. I am a total newb at C# so please be patient with me.

Comment: dt lives in the other void too so how do i reference it?

Comment: Move the definition of dt from inside a method to outside a method. Table would become a property of the class.

Comment: Hi, yeah I did that thanks and it works. What  I didn't realise (being a C# Newb) is that although dt gets updated, that doesn't update the source table in SQL server. My plan for that step is to pass the contents of dt to a TVP in a SPROC. Pro's and cons of that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference in this case.  Speed depends on Processor, memory, and amount of data transferred.  Also Entity driver is better than SQL client.   And the SQL Server software is multi-threaded when doing a query.  On queries that return large amounts of data I will run sqlcmd.exe (a msdn command line app) and save data to a csv file.  Then read csv into c#.  A query that takes 1/2 hour from c# will take less than 5 minutes in sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: Ok so the entire project is to allow certain non technical staff to update and add reference codes to a table in SQL Server. The maximum columns and records should be about 10x100. I think the .CSV thing is a great idea but I won’t be transferring enough data to warrant it. Will still look into Entity Driver. Thanks for the help. Dave

Comment: Why c#?  You could use the SQL Server command line utilities like sqlcmd.exe which takes CSV inputs and uses a SQL Query.  If you did use c# front end for the database   You could let staff do everything in Excel. Even write a VBA macro to save into SQL Server.  Why c#???????

Comment: OK chill with the ? please. I am learning C# and this seems like a good project to do. I have used VBA for years so that wouldn't present a challenge for me. Cheers for the info,Dave

Comment: You have "non technical staff" using the app.  These people already know how to use Excel.  Do you want to train these people on a new app?  SQLCMD.EXE already has the CSV interface.  Even PowerShell has build in commands (I believe these are an interface to sqlcmd.exe) to load csv into the database. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It's not 1998 so I prefer to not use Excel thanks.

Comment: But Microsoft is still updating and releasing new versions like 365.  Old Programs never die, they still keeping Excelling Away.